# Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Tags: function-construction, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to write this Mathematica function to find the optimal price for a model, given some model parameters. This is a stylized example of what I'm trying to do, and I'm wondering what's a better way to do it. The code below takes a while to run (at least on my computer).

```
U[x_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ, a_?NumericQ] := 
 RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[ 
   (a*v - p - x >= 0 && 0 <= v <= 1 ) , {v}]]
q[p_?NumericQ, 
  a_?NumericQ] := (x /. 
   FindRoot[x - U[x, p, a] == 0, {x, 0.00001, 0, 1}])
Purchase[p_, a_] := RegionMeasure[ImplicitRegion[ 
   {(a*v - p - x >= 0  && 0 <= v <= 1) /. {x -> q[p, a]}} // 
    Evaluate , {v}]]
bestPrice[a_] := 
 p /. Last[NMaximize[{p*Purchase[p, a], 0 <= p <= a}, p]] 

bestPrice[2]
```

Is there a faster optimization function for this problem then `NMaximize`? The `Purchase[]` function measures the total demand for the model, and the `bestPrice[]` function figures out the optimal price to maximize the profit, given the model parameter 'a'. In the full model I have, there is more than one model parameter and several conditions within the `Purchase[]` function and `U[]` function, so I'm wondering how I can make this simple example go faster. If you have any ideas, please let me know. Thanks in advacnce!

Comment: Could you write out the optimization problem more explicitly in LaTeX or give a diagram? There might be a linear programming solution.

Answer (score 2):

I think nothing will beat

```
 bestPrice[a_] := a/2;
```

Why do I believe that this is true? Well, first I observed that

```
U[x_, p_, a_] := 1 - Clip[(x + p)/a, {0, 1}]
```

Now

```
Simplify[Solve[x - U[x, p, a] == 0, x], {a >= p >= 0}]
```

returns

> {{x -> Undefined}, {x -> Undefined}, {x -> ConditionalExpression[(a - p)/(1 + a), a > p && p > 0]}}

wich makes me believe that

```
q[p_, a_] := (a - p)/(1 + a)
```

Substituted, we deduce that

```
Purchase[p_, a_] := 1 - Clip[(1 + p)/(1 + a), {0, 1}];
```

and because of `0 <= p <= a`, `(1 + p)/(1 + a)` is always between 0 and 1, hence

```
Purchase[p_, a_] := 1 - (1 + p)/(1 + a);
```

So the objective is actually the function

```
f[p_] := p (1 - (1 + p)/(1 + a))
```

and

```
Solve[f'[p] == 0, p]
```

yields

> {{p -> a/2}}

Moreover, `f''[p]` equals `-(2/(1 + a))` which must be negative. So `f` is a downward pointing parabola and its unique critical point $a/2$ lies in the interior of the interval $[0,a]$. Hence it must be the maximum.

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to figure this out numerically. This is a 'toy example' meant to illustrate the problem as simply as possible. In this case, it's possible to figure out the optimal solution quickly, but the actual problem involves many different sub-regions, conditions, cases, etc.

Answer (score 1):

We can reduce time by 6.66 times (on my computer) using `Module` instead of functions with `?NumericQ`

```
price[a_] := 
 Module[{x, v, p}, 
  u = RegionMeasure[
    ImplicitRegion[(a*v - p - x >= 0 && 0 <= v <= 1), {v}]];
  Q = (x /. FindRoot[x - u == 0, {x, 0.00001, 0, 1}]);
  purchase = 
   RegionMeasure[
    ImplicitRegion[{(a*v - p - x >= 0 && 0 <= v <= 1) /. {x -> Q}} // 
      Evaluate, {v}]];
  bp = p /. Last[NMaximize[{p*purchase, 0 <= p <= a}, p]]; bp]

price[2] // AbsoluteTiming

Out[]= {7.50122, 1.}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! That speeds it up quite a bit.